# How to remove the Google search bar?

Tags: app-widgets, google-pixel, google-search

How can I remove the Google search bar from the main screen? It's taking up screen space and I'm not using it.
I have a Pixel running 8.1.0.
I found ways to remove it from other models and versions, but not mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Pixel phones rely on an exclusive "Pixel Launcher". For Google to be able to push itself more onto the user, the search bar is made permanent.

There is currently no way to hide/remove the search bar from Pixel Launcher. If the bar hurts you a lot, then you need to switch to a different launcher. *Nova Launcher* is one such highly recommended launcher.

Comment: I tried Nova Launcher and it is pretty much what I was looking for. Though, it seems that it uses more battery power than "normal".

Comment: Might be happening that way. However, for me, it just gives almost the same output from the battery. You should usually stop android from adding any sort of battery optimization on the launcher. As it essentially always needs to run. If android tries to stop it and then a re-run would cause it to consume more power than actually staying in background.